# CE amplifier with +-5% resistors range

Tags: amplifier

[image: CE amplifier schematic]

I am studying on CE amplifiers and I am getting a bit confused when the resistors range enters the game. I cannot figure out which resistors should I increase and which should I decrease to find the Vout max, the Vout min, the Qhigh and the Qlow (on resting place graph). Lets say that our resistors have a +-5% range.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking. To get the highest possibly Vout, set RL= 0Ω, done, the rest literally doesn't matter after that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you mean set RL to infinity (this assumes that Vout max and Vout min are RMS values, which we must assume in the absence of other info).

Comment: @Andyaka, hm with R_L= you get Vout==Vcc, and the RMS of that is Vcc, doesn't get any higher in a Vcc-powered circuit?

Comment: Lets say that all the resistors have a range of+-5% of it's value (eg 1K resistor can take values from 950 to 1050 Ohms). Lets say that R1=10K, R2=2K, RL=5K, RC=1K. All of those values can be increased or decreased by +5% or -5%. Which combination of those incresed and decreased values should I choose in order to find the Vout max, the Vout min, the Qhigh and the Qlow

Comment: You have few enough resistors here that you can just iterate through each possibility (it's safe to assume that the highest and lowest values will be with some combination of highest and lowest possible resistances), so I'd say just go through each possibiliity and see which gives you the highest or lowest output.

Comment: When I was in school, we used a spreadsheet.  Plugged all the formulas in and then changed the values of each R and C an saw the results, one row per change. Tedious, but this gave us a feeling for how the part values affected the performance of the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a circuit you can play around (double click on elements to change their values)](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%2023.47059216675035%2050%205%2043%0At%20304%2048%20384%2048%200%201%20-4.383199460622562%200.6184643562342096%20100%0Av%20224%20128%20224%2048%200%201%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ac%20224%2048%20304%2048%200%200.000001%201.1545695802023577%0Ar%20304%20-32%20304%2048%200%203000%0Ar%20304%2048%20304%20128%200%201000%0Aw%20224%20128%20304%20128%200%0Ag%20224%20128%20224%20176%200%0AR%20304%20-32%20304%20-80%200%200%2040%2015%200%200%200.5%0Aw%20304%20-32%20384%20-32%200%0Ar%20384%2064%20384%20128%200%201200%0Aw%20304%20128%20384%20128%200%0Ac%20464%2064%20464%20128%200%200.000001%203.211305261867004%0Aw%20384%20128%20464%20128%200%0Aw%20384%2032%20512%2032%200%0Ax%20419%203%20449%206%204%2024%20RL%0Ax%20406%20105%20439%20108%204%2024%20RE%0Aw%20384%2064%20464%2064%200%0Ar%20384%20-32%20384%2032%200%202800%0A403%20-32%2016%20128%20128%200%201_64_0_4099_5_0.00625_0_2_1_3%0A403%20560%20-48%20864%20128%200%2013_64_0_4099_20_0.00009765625_0_2_13_3%0A38%209%200%200%2010000%20RE%0A38%2017%200%200%2010000%20RL%0A)
All resistors matter in different ways, so it is hard to answer the question but to let you experiment. The only rule of thumb here is try to make sure the mean value of Vout is around the middle of Vcc+